# diagram using xymatrix

Tags: xy-pic

i would like to reproduce this exact diagramme 
[image: lambda]

i used the xymatrix package put the scaling was awful 
this is the script

```
\xymatrix{
&(\lambda x. x x) ((\lambda x. y) z ) \ar[dl]_{} \ar[dr]^{} &\\
((\lambda x. y) z) ((\lambda x. y) z)   & &(\lambda x.x x) y \ar[dl]_{}\\
&y y&}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point is `@C-2pc@R+1pc` that decreases the space between columns and increases the space between rows. The `\hphantom` and `\makebox` trick is for getting it more symmetric.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}

\[
\hphantom{((\lambda x. y) z)}
\xymatrix@C-2pc@R+1pc{
&(\lambda x. x x) ((\lambda x. y) z ) \ar[dl]_{} \ar[dr]^{} &\\
\makebox[0pt][r]{$((\lambda x. y) z)$} ((\lambda x. y) z)   & &(\lambda x.x x) y \ar[dl]_{}\\
&y y&
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hmmm.  those arrows aren't *quite* perpendicular to one another.  might not "narrowing" the expression on the first line (with an equal negative `\hspace*` on either side of the expression) remedy that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `tikz-cd`. The arrow declaration in the preamble is optional of course.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{%
    ,commutative diagrams/.cd
    ,arrow style=tikz
    ,diagrams={>=LaTeX}
    }

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[sep={2cm,between origins}]
    & (\lambda x. x x) ((\lambda x. y) z ) \arrow{dl}\arrow{dr} & \\
    ((\lambda x. y) z) ((\lambda x. y) z) & & (\lambda x.x x) y \arrow{dl} \\
    & yy\vphantom{)} &
\end{tikzcd}
\]  
\end{document}
```

[image]